# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gothonweb2' in python

Tags: python, automated-tests, python-module, web.py

My error is like

```
(base) C:\Users\lenovo\projects\gothonweb2>python bin/app.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bin/app.py", line 2, in <module>
    from gothonweb2 import map
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gothonweb2'
```

The project directory is

C:\Users\lenovo\projects\gothonweb2

```
bin
   __init__.py
   app.py
gothonweb2
   __init__.py
   web.py
templates
  layout.html
  show_room.html
  you_died.html
tests
   __init__.py
   app_tests.py
   map_tests.py
   tools.py
```

The code in bin/app.py is :

```
import web
from gothonweb2 import map
import urllib.request
urls=(
    '/game','GameEngine',
    '/','Index',
)
app=web.application(urls,globals())
#Title hack so that debug mode works with sessions
if web.config.get('_session') is None:
    store=web.session.DiskStore('sessions')
    session=web.session.Session(app,store,initializer={'room':None})
    web.config._session=session
else:
    session=web.config._session
render=web.template.render('templates/',base="layout")
class Index(object):
    def GET(self):
    #this is use to"setup"the session with starting values
        session.room=map.START
        web.seeother("/game")
class GameEngine(object):
    def GET(self):
        if session.room:
            return render.show_room(room=session.room)
        else:
            return render.you_died()
    def POST(self):
        form=web.input(action=None)
        #there is a bug here,can you fix it?
        if session.room and form.action:
            session.room=session.room.go(form.action)
        web.seeother("/game")
if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run()
```

I got the error just as  above. Also the project's path and the import gothonweb2 part are also above. I don't know why it returns 'No module named 'gothonweb2''. Can someone help me?

Comment: please include your code and things like output and directory structure in the question **as text**, not images

Comment: Please look at basic guidelines how to structure a python project http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/structure/

Comment: @Phydeaux  I've changed the format from pictures to text now.

Comment: @ibt23sec5 Thanks, I will read the guidelines. Do you think there is a problem in my project structure? I just followed the structure in a popular python book Learn Python the Hard Way.

Comment: I just tried to put the file gothonweb2 into bin file, and this time it works.@ibt23sec5

Comment: Thank you@ibt23sec5